# SQL ограничение значений

Tags: mysql, sql

DOBROGO денечка, случайный прохожий!
Имею 2 таблицы: skill (id, name) и developer (id, name, skills). Возможно ли поставить ограничение, что бы в таблицу developer в столбец skills, можно было добавить только то значение, которое существует в таблице skill? И если это возможно, то подскажите пожалуйста как написать такой запрос! Спасибо!

Пишу небольшое CRUD приложение, поэтому если это будет выборка, было еще лучше!

Comment: Не можно, а нужно. Ваши таблицы должны быть связаны. В таблице developer должен быть внешний ключ на skill_id. Добавьте связь и в skill_id таблицы developer вы сможете записывать только существующие записи из таблицы skill.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно для этой цели и существуют внешние ключи (FOREIGN KEY) - сервер проверяет наличие значения в другой таблице и блокирует изменения, если такого значения нет. Чтобы эта связь была более очевидной, крайне желательно, чтобы оба поля (и то, которое ссылается, и то, на которое ссылается) имели в точности одно и то же имя.

В Вашем случае это может быть, например, так:

```sql
CREATE TABLE skill ( skill_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     name VARCHAR(255) );
```

и

```sql
CREATE TABLE developer ( developer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                         name VARCHAR(255), 
                         skill_id INT,
                         CONSTRAINT skill_id FOREIGN KEY (skill_id) REFERENCES skill (skill_id) );
```

Теперь в таблицу `developer` в поле `skill_id` можно вставить только значение, которое уже имеется в таблице `skill` в поле `skill_id`. Либо можно вставить значение NULL.

Если же поле обязательно для заполнения, то его следует дополнительно объявить как NOT NULL, и тогда вставляемое значение должно быть строго имеющимся в таблице `skill`.

Обратите внимание. Тип данных обеих полей строго совпадает (INT). Если, например, в одной таблице оно объявлено как беззнаковое, то и в другой оно должно быть таким же - иначе связь не создастся.

Кроме того, оба поля должны быть индексированы. В таблице `developer` такой индекс будет создан автоматически при создании ограничения (constraint), если он не существует, а вот в таблице, на которую ссылаемся, он обязан быть создан заранее

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!